# Distributing n candies to n children

Tags: probability

What is the probability of any child getting two or more candies?

My thinking is that if there is one child getting 2 candies, that means there is one child not getting any candies.

So $(n-1/n)^n$ would be the answer.

But for $n = 2$, the distribution is

```
1 1
0 2
2 0
```

which means $(n-1/n)^n$ is not correct.

Can someone give me an hint on how to approach this question?

Comment: hi: the probability of that is 1 minus the probability of every child getting one candle. So, if you can figure out that probability, you are done. If you have trouble with that, let us know. I don't want to give the whole answer away because it's good to practice with these things.

Comment: 1 - $ \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} ((n-i)/n) $ make sense to me, but why is ((n-1)/n)^n not correct? Isn't the probability of any children getting two or more candies, the probability of always selecting n-1 children

Comment: The event that any child gets two or more candles can happen in so many ways. For example, one child could get all the candles. So, I'm not clear where the ((n-1)/n)^n is coming from. Calculate the probability of every child getting one candle and you are basically done.  You can do this by calculating ( total number of ways that each child can get one candle ) divided by (the total number of ways of giving out the candles ).

Comment: Note that it's often easier to calculate the "opposite" event and then do 1 minus that rather than calculating the probability of the event directly. Take this problem: It's not easy to calculate the number of ways that atleast one child can get more than one candle. There are too many ways. So, instead, you calculate the probability that it won't happen and then do 1 minus that.

Comment: $\left(n-\frac1n\right)^n >1$ for $n>1$, so is not a probability.  Or did you mean $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$?

Comment: Your example with $n=2$ seems to suggest $\frac23$, but I would have said $\frac24=\frac12$  if you give the first candy to the first child with probability $\frac12$ and independently  you give the second candy to the first child with probability $\frac12$. Still not $\left(2-\frac12\right)^2$ or  $\left(\frac{2-1}{2}\right)^2$, but consistent with your comment of  $1-\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} ((n-i)/n) = 1-\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Comment: olaf: I'm not sure if you got the answer but, if you didn't and want one, it goes like this. There's only one way that you can give each child a candle. Also, there are $n^n$ ways that you give out the candles ( because there are n candles and n slots to put them in ). So, the probability that atleast 1 child gets 2 or more candles is $(1 - \frac{1}{n^n})$. I hope this makes sense. If not, let us know.

Comment: Olaf: Henry is correct. I was wrong. The number of ways to put 1 candle in each slot is $n!$ rather than 1 because you have $n$ candles to pick when picking a candle for the first slot, $(n-1)$ candles to pick for the second slot and so on. So, the total number of ways to give each child one candle is $n!$. Therefore the probability is $(1 - \frac{n!}{n^n})$. So, my numerator was wrong.  my apologies and thanks to Henry for correction.